# Create new columns from columns with lists

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do this with `python` and `pandas`.

Let's suppose that I have the following:

```
    x_position  y_position
0   [4, 2, 6]   [1, 2, 9]
1   [1, 7]      [3, 5]
```

and I finally want to have the following:

```
    x_position  y_position  new_0_0 new_0_1 new_1_0 new_1_1 new_2_0 new_2_1
0   [4, 2, 6]   [1, 2, 9]   4       1       2       2       6       9
1   [1, 7]      [3, 5]      1       3       7       5       Na      Na
```

It is not necessary that the new columns have names such as `new_0_0`; it can be `0_0` or even anything to be honest.

Secondly, it would be good if your code can work for more columns with lists e.g. with a z_position column too.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension with DataFrame constructor and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), sorting by second level of `Multiindex` in columns by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df)
  x_position y_position z_position
0  [4, 2, 6]  [1, 2, 9]    [4,8,9]
1     [1, 7]     [3, 5]      [1,3]

comp = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist()) for x in df.columns]
df1 = pd.concat(comp, axis=1, keys=range(len(df.columns))).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = [f'new_{b}_{a}' for a, b in df1.columns]
print (df1)
   new_0_0  new_0_1  new_0_2  new_1_0  new_1_1  new_1_2  new_2_0  new_2_1  \
0        4        1        4        2        2        8      6.0      9.0   
1        1        3        1        7        5        3      NaN      NaN   

   new_2_2  
0      9.0  
1      NaN  

print (df.join(df1))
  x_position y_position z_position  new_0_0  new_0_1  new_0_2  new_1_0  \
0  [4, 2, 6]  [1, 2, 9]  [4, 8, 9]        4        1        4        2   
1     [1, 7]     [3, 5]     [1, 3]        1        3        1        7   

   new_1_1  new_1_2  new_2_0  new_2_1  new_2_2  
0        2        8      6.0      9.0      9.0  
1        5        3      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: By the way, it would be a bit good to make clear at your post what should change at your code if we have more or fewer columns. For example I think that `keys=range(3)` should change for example to `keys=range(4)` if the number of original columns is 4 or am I missing something?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - exactly.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - same like `range(len(df.columns))`

Comment: how about using `df.explode`? i thought this would be a good use case (: (i don't have the latest version of pandas at my work station otherwise i'd have a try!)

Comment: @Datanovice - Exactly same problem, but here it is not exploding, so DataFrame constructoris good.

Comment: ah of course, i didn't read the sample output properly. Thanks as always jezrael

Comment: By the way, the order of the rows is preserved right? (in the sense that df1 has the same order of rows as df).

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - yes, order is preserved.

Comment: Ok so I assume that you do `join` instead of `concat` at the end (`print (df.join(df1))`) because in principle it is better to do the former in case the order was not preserved?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - I think order is not change if use `join` of `concat(axis=1)` code. only necessary default index in original. If index is different, is necessary set it in `comp = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist()) for x in df.columns]` like `comp = [pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist(), index=df.index) for x in df.columns]`

Comment: Cool, by the way I did not mean that the order will change either if you use join or concat. I said that by using concat you do not in general assume that the order is necessarily the same and this is why you join by index instead of simply concatenating. In any case, I think that the index in the end is the same; I just asked you because you know better what the code does.