# How can I create a new columns from a column with lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that contains lists of items. I want to create 3 columns that will have each item in the list.
Here is the dataframe: Where the list has 2 elements, I need the first element to be in the **age** column while the remaining element to be in the **weight** column and where there is only one element, I want it to be in the **age** column.

```
| First_Name | Others               |
| ---------- | -------------------- |
| Ken        | ["Batman","28","5.5" |
| Cole       | ["36","6.1"          |
| Eddie      | ["24"                |
```

I would like to get this output:

```
| First_Name | Others               | Surname | Age | Weight |
| ---------- | -------------------- |-------- | --- | ------ |
| Ken        | ["Batman","28","55"  | Batman  | 28  | 55     |
| Cole       | ["36","60"           |  NaN    | 36  | 60     |
| Eddie      | ["81"                |  NaN    | 81  | NaN    |
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359379/create-new-columns-from-columns-with-lists) method but it is not giving me the results as I would like it to be. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using Pandas [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function here.

```
df[["Surname","Age","Weight"]] = df['Others'].str.extract(r'\["(?:([^"]*)",")?(\d+)(?:","(\d+))?"',expand=False)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
  First_Name               Others Surname Age Weight
0        Ken  ["Batman","28","55"  Batman  28     55
1       Cole           ["36","60"      36  60    NaN
2      Eddie                ["81"     NaN  81    NaN
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above used regex.

```
\["            ##Matching literal [" here.
(?:            ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
  ([^"]*)","   ##Matching everything till " in 1st capturing group, followed by "," here.
)?             ##Closing 1st non-capturing group here.
(\d+)          ##Matching 1 or more digits in 2nd capturing group here.
(?:            ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
  ","          ##Matching "," here.
  (\d+)        ##Matching 1 or more digits here in 3rd capturing group.
)?             ##Closing non-capturing group here.
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It works on the first row but doesn't achieve what I needed in the second row since I need age to be 36 and weight 60.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to guess the column name for non-equal sized lists.

In other cases you can use [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```py
new_columns = data["Others"].apply(pd.Series, index=["Surname", "Age", "Weight"])
# insert new_columns using pd.concat
pd.concat([data, new_columns], axis=1)
```

You can also use the smarter apply function, something like this:

```py
def func(others):
    index = ["Surname", "Age", "Weight"]
    if others[0].isnumeric():
        # the first item in the array is numeric, so it probably 'Age'
        return pd.Series([""] + others, index)
    return pd.Series(others, index)

new_columns = data["Others"].apply(func)
```

The idea is to return `pd.Series` from the apply method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Try with `lstrip()` ,`replace()`,`split()`,`fillna()`, `apply()` and `to_numeric()` method:

```
df[['Surname','Age','Weight']]=df['Others'].str.lstrip('[').str.split(',',expand=True).replace('"','',regex=True)

df['Weight']=df['Weight'].fillna(df['Age'])
df['Age']=pd.to_numeric(df['Surname'],errors='coerce').fillna(df['Age'])
df['Surname']=df['Surname'].apply(lambda x:x if x.isalpha() else float("NaN"))
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output